# Reading data from a file and storing it into a vector

Tags: c++

I'm trying to read a list of items from from a file and then store them into a vector. The issue is my code is adding the last item to the vector twice and I'm not sure why the it keeps reading the file even though the program has reached the end.

Here's what's in the text file. The "Oranges" line appears twice when I display the contents of the vector.

Apples-pounds-10 2

Oranges-pounds-5 6

Here's the code
//Read the contents of the list to a file

```
while (!inputFile.fail())
{   

    //Extract the line from the list
    getline(inputFile,item_name,'-');
    getline(inputFile,item_unit,'-');
    inputFile >> item_amount;
    inputFile >> item_price;

    //Create an instance of the item object
    Item New_Item(item_name, item_unit, item_amount,item_price);

    //Push it to the list vector
    list.push_back(New_Item);
}

//Close the file
inputFile.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the "fail" flag is not set until you make an attempt at reading some more data from the file. Here is a quick way of fixing this:

```
for (;;) {
    //Extract the line from the list
    getline(inputFile,item_name,'-');
    getline(inputFile,item_unit,'-');
    inputFile >> item_amount;
    inputFile >> item_price;
    if (inputFile.fail()) break;
    //Create an instance of the item object
    Item New_Item(item_name, item_unit, item_amount,item_price);
    //Push it to the list vector
    list.push_back(New_Item);
}
```

If this is for a learning exercise, and you have not learn the `>>` operator yet, this should do it. Otherwise, the `operator>>` approach is better.

Answer (score 2):

This is a typical symptom of the `while (!infile.fail())` anti-pattern.

I'd define a struct and overload `operator>>` for that type:

```
struct item { 
    std::string name;
    std::string unit;
    int amount;
    int price;
};

std::istream &std::operator>>(std::istream &is, item &i) { 
    getline(is, i.name, '-');
    getline(is, i.unit, '-');
    is >> i.amount;
    return is >> i.price;
}
```

With those defined, reading the data borders on trivial:

```
std::ifstream inputFile("fileNameHere");

std::vector<New_Item> items { std::istream_iterator<Item>(inputFile),
                              std::istream_iterator<Item>() };
```

[I changed it from `list` to `vector`, because, well, you really don't want `list`. You can change it back, but probably shouldn't.]